# How to find between 2 dates whichever comes first

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I tried to find someone between 2 dates earlier in the year or month and it didn't work

```
converteDateToDatePipe(dCheck: Date, d1: Date): boolean {
   var d11 = this.pipe.transform(d1, 'shortDate');
   var dCc = this.pipe.transform(dCheck, 'shortDate');
   var dd11 = new Date(d11);
   var ddcc = new Date(dCc);
   if (dd11 <= ddcc)
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I get it `dCheck` is a date and `d1` is also a date. What are you transforming?

Comment: `return (dd11 <= ddcc);` would be enough no need the `if` condition

Comment: Chances are you are not parsing the string correctly. Why not use [`momentjs`](https://momentjs.com/) or something similar?

Comment: `return (dCheck.getTime()<= d1.getTime());` seems will produce the desired result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
  test(){
    let first = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 111111);
    let second = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 22222);
    let nextDate = this.nextDate(first, second);

    console.log(second.getTime() === nextDate.getTime())
  }


  nextDate(first: Date, second: Date): Date {

    let currentDay = new Date();
    let firstDiff = currentDay.getTime() - first.getTime();
    let secondDiff = currentDay.getTime() - second.getTime();

    return (firstDiff >= secondDiff) ? first : second;
  }
```